# Why <body> has the certain width, if there is no width property in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a header with 100% width and grey line under it. The line should use 100% width of the browser window. But when I reduce the browser width the grey line doesn't take the whole width of the webpage. Why? Strange, but a body tag takes certain width value although no width setted up for the body in css. Please, check the picture below and the code. Thanks a lot!

If you reduce browser width, there is a problem: no grey border on the right  any more!
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B35EX-b9d628ZmxBWFJjOTF1eFU/view

Here is the code

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Max's Icebrrrg</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="headerInner">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1>Icebrrrg</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="mainNav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Three Column</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sidebar Right</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sidebar Left</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Full Width</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="contentWrapper">

    </div>

    <footer>

    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
}

body {
    font: 14px/21px "HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    color: #444;
}



/******************** HEADER ************************/

header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E8;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.headerInner {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
    width: 157px;
    height: 63px;
    background: url(../img/icebrrrg-logo.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    margin: 22px 0;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}

.logo h1 {
    text-indent: -99999px;
}

.mainNav {
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}

.mainNav ul {
    margin: 44px 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}

.mainNav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2C88C9;
    padding: 48px 10px 43px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;
}

.mainNav a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #2C88C9;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a problem in the JsFiddle i put together using your HTML/CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/57k17amb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thin is your `.headerInner` has a fixed `width: 960px` and the `body` as well  the `<header>` stretch to the width of the screen by default so when it is less than 960px your `.headerInner` overflow the `<header>`

To fix it just move the `border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E8;` from `<header>` to `.headerInner`

[Here a working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/qqpc3L1o/)

Or keep the border in its place and set `width: 960px;` and `margin: 0 auto` to `header` .

[Here the jsfiddle in this way](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/vq2tamvy/1/)

If you want that the border stretch to the screen do this:

```
header {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    min-width: 960px;    
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E8;
}
```

[And here the jsfiddle for this one](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/a44d4sh7)

Comment: Thanks! But I need the grey line to take the whole 100% width of the browser. If I do as you offered, the grey line will be 960px only!

Comment: @Max I update my answer to grey line to take the whole 100% width of the browser, let me know if now works as you want.

Comment: I'm glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can check with the below link. I have removed the css related to .logo h1 mentioned below.

http://jsfiddle.net/57k17amb/1/

```
.logo h1 {
    text-indent: -99999px;
}
```

Comment: You're not explaining anything. Why do you include that CSS in your answer?